# CoordinatorLayout / RelativeLayout issue within a ViewSwitcher

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-coordinatorlayout, viewswitcher

This is a follow up question of this one: [Coordinator Layout and Relative Layout issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820709/coordinator-layout-and-relative-layout-issue)

I have an issue when you have a `CoordinatorLayout` with a `RelativeLayout` within a `ViewSwitcher` like the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ViewSwitcher  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/switcher">

    <!--First switcher view / Splash Screen-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--Second switcher view-->
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.example.test">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <!--as @LinX64 suggested in previous question-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:text="text"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </RelativeLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</ViewSwitcher>
```

And this in my `Activity`:

```
final ViewSwitcher switcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);

//If I use switcher.showNext() as soon the activity starts, everything works fine.

new CountDownTimer(1500, 1500) {
   @Override
   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

   @Override
   public void onFinish() {
       switcher.showNext();
   }
}.start();
```

**Result:** (Screenshot taken from `Moto G` `Android` 5.1)

[image]

As you can see, the button isn't at bottom of the screen and it's been cropped.

**Expected result:**

[image]

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.example.test"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Styles**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</resources>
```

Comment: It's working on real device :)

Comment: The screenshot was taken from a real device, Moto G 4G, Android 5.1 :(

Comment: Weird: 4.4.2 : http://i.imgur.com/rUHrxq1.png

Comment: Also in Motorola MC40 android 4 (Can't remember exact version)

Comment: You should really be using a [launch theme](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd) for a splash screen and skip the artificial delay and `ViewSwitcher` entirely.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Ok maybe I should, But let's say I'm using a ViewSwitcher for other thing, the problem stands.. and thanks about that link ;)

Comment: That height looks like it of the notification bar, which style are you using in the manifest?

Comment: @rekire Android studio generated manifest, android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"

Comment: Did you change anything in the styles.xml / your style?

Comment: No, I did not, it's just a newly created blank activity in android studio, I'll post the styles.xml & manifest.

Comment: @rekire updated the question with manifest & styles.

Comment: Thx, after reviewing it a second time I would try to change the layout to make the `CoordinatorLayout` to the root layout.

Comment: Coordinator Layout > View Switcher > (Views)x2 ?

Comment: Well you are right that doesn't make sense... Try adding the  `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` attribute to your `ViewSwitcher` tag, but I suspect that this will cause some graphic glitches in the notificationbar area while the splashscreen is visible.

Comment: Just for testing I would remove the splash screen things, having only the coordinator layout as root.

Comment: Only the coordinator Layout work, that was solved in my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820709/coordinator-layout-and-relative-layout-issue the problem is how to achieve that with a view switcher. I want to understand why it doesn't work. When it does work if I just enter the activity and executes switcher.showNext() without delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Worked for me with `runOnUiThread(new Runnable()`** after working on it

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Handler mHandler;
    private ViewSwitcher switcher;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        switcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
        mHandler = new Handler();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000); // every 5 seconds
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            switcher.showNext();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        });

    }


}
```

And of course, `XML`:

```
<!--as @LinX64 suggested in previous question-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:text="text"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Using your example, the first view of the view switcher isn't shown (Splash screen), all blank, 5 seconds later, with a tiny flicker I see the view (With the button at the bottom)

Comment: yeah, but that problem solved i guess, trying to fix Splash too.

Comment: If I can't see the first view of the view switcher, the problem isn't solved, since the viewswitcher isn't used at all, I just see the second view. Expected result: Splash Screen - Delay (5 seconds) - Activity main layout. With your example: Blank Screen - Delay (5 secs) - Main Layout.

Comment: yeah, but seems like that `runOnUiThread(new Runnable();` can fix that button.

Comment: Kinda buggy but yes, beacause it flickers a little (I don't mind it) It appears cropped, and and then it shows correctly a few milliseconds later.

Comment: That's why i told you let's create an another question :)

Comment: That's why I did it :)

Comment: Well I would use for that switching a handler with postDelayed().